# upload image in flickr from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flickr

I am developing a application where i want to load the image on flickr.I have seen the Snap and Run project where i tried to share the image using my API key but cannot do it. 
its giving response as invalid callback url. Can anyone help me with this as I am not able to do this,,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I also use "Snap and Run" project as reference. But in simulator, after authorization, number "123-896-215" generated and tell me that include this number in your application. At which place should I include above number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ObjectiveFlickr project: http://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

You'll need to give us more detail if you want a better answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
i have implemented  code from Objective Flickr and example Snap and Run is from that this project only. Its only giving problem to me..

Comment: Well unless you give us more information you aren't going to get any help. How could anyone know where your "Snap and Run" example came from? You didn't say. You also haven't given detailed information about what errors you are seeing or even really what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well im integrated the objectiveflickr code given by flickr API. and there we have snap and run sample project to execute. u can check from flickr API directly.

Comment: upload image objectiveflickr provided code
    NSInputStream *imageStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:imageData];
    [request uploadImageStream:imageStream suggestedFilename:@"Foobar.jpg" MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"is_public", nil]];
but its not working

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer, could you please give a reason? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for all your support. i am able to uploading image into flickr

Comment: hey maddy i am using "Snap and Run" and i get error regarding the library and not able to compile it. What did u do? Kindly post ur solution

Comment: @RobKeniger:I also use "Snap and Run" project as reference. But in simulator, after authorization, number "123-896-215" generated and tell me that include this number in your application. At which place should I include above number?

Comment: @BK Library need to build with device & simulator separately & include both .a files in project.

Comment: @Madhu which flickr API method was used by you to upload your photo? Actually i found methods for upload photo in photo set or in gallery using add photo method. But i want to add directly to my profile. Not in gallery nor in photoset